# Why do they call an absolute value a modulus?

Tags: calculus

why do they call an absolute value a modulus? all it does is flipping minus sign

etymology book says it is a module

but sometimes people call an inverse of some thing is a modulus

module is a some kind of self sufficient subroutine

Answer (score 2):

The word modulus comes from latin language, and it means "(small) measure". Since the absolute value can be interpreted, physically, as the measure "distance from origin", it makes sense to use the word "modulus" in this context